# Find the sample size $n$ for a stratified sampling method

Tags: sampling, sampling-theory, risk-assessment

Let’s say we have a finite population $N=5000$.We have divided the population into 5 subgroups according to a risk characteristic  “very low risk”,”low risk”,”medium risk”,”high risk” and “very high risk” according to how possible is not to pay taxes.

So we have stratification with  $L = 5$
With subpopulations in each stratum
$N_{L=1}=1000$,$N_{L=2}=1000$,$N_{L=3}=1000$,$N_{L=4}=1000$,$N_{L=5}=1000$

We are asked from this stratified design the sample size must contain $5\%$ of the very low risk level,$5\%,10\%,20\%$ and $20\%$ respectively for the other categories.
Now the 60% of the sample will be according to this "risk weighted"
How can someone determine the $n$ sample size from this allocation?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your sampling scheme.

Comment: @311411  I have edited my question.hopes this clearer.

Comment: Why don't the populations in the second stratification add up to $15000$?

Comment: I made it simpler

Comment: If I understand correctly, 60 percent of your final sample will be 600 individuals. So if you obtain 400 different individuals by some other (unspecified) method, then $n=1000$. However the scheme seems strange, so I wonder if I have understood you correctly.

Comment: Let’s say that I have one scheme.Forget the second scheme for now.How I will obtain the sample size n with these requirements?